# Get the indices of numbers in a string and extract words before and after the number (in different languages)

Tags: python, regex, nlp, text-extraction

I tried using regex and found numbers but not finding the indices for the entire number, instead getting index it only for the first character in the number

```
text = "४०० pounds of wheat at $ 3 per pound"
numero = re.finditer(r"(\d+)", text) ####
op = re.findall(r"(\d+)", text) ####

indices = [m.start() for m in numero]
OUTPUT

[0, 25]

***Expected OUTPUT***
[0, 6]
```

After finding the exact indices and storing in a list, it would be easier to extract the words. This is what I believe? What do you think?

Also, I am expecting words at different positions so it cannot be a static approach

Comment: Why do you expect (0,6)?  The "3" starts at character 25.  You only printed the starting index (`m.start()`).  You can call `m.match()` to get the string that matched.

Comment: I am considering each word as a index, so the first number "४००" is at position 0 followed by 3 at position 6, need to save the get the index for traversing the string to get words before and after the number

Comment: That's not how `re` works, of course.  It knows nothing about words.  It returns pairs of column numbers.  From that, you can trivially extract the words you want.

Comment: Can you suggest any other option other than re to deal with this problem?

Comment: What problem?  If you want to work with words, then you will have to split the string into words and run the regular expression against each word individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question with [nlp](/questions/tagged/nlp) tag and it is a [python](/questions/tagged/python) question, why don't you use ***[`Spacy`](https://spacy.io/usage#quickstart)***?

See an Python demo with Spacy 3.0.1:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
text = "४०० pounds of wheat at $ 3 per pound"
doc = nlp(text)
print([(token.text, token.i) for token in doc if token.is_alpha])
## => [('pounds', 1), ('of', 2), ('wheat', 3), ('at', 4), ('per', 7), ('pound', 8)]
## => print([(token.text, token.i) for token in doc if token.like_num])
[('४००', 0), ('3', 6)]
```

Here,

- `nlp` object is initialized with the English "big" model
- `doc` is the Spacy document initialized with your `text` variable
- `[(token.text, token.i) for token in doc if token.is_alpha]` gets you a list of letter words with their values (`token.text`) and their positions in the document (`token.i`)
- `[(token.text, token.i) for token in doc if token.like_num]` fetches the list of numbers with their positions inside the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, just had one doubt can I access the text at a specific location if I have indices in a list, eg: I have [0,6] in list which are numbers. I want the text at position 1 and 7 but this is dynamic so can change each time

Comment: @SharanIyer I am not sure what you want. Get a substring from a string? `text[start:end]`? If you mean you need the text only from the above, you could use `numbers = [(token.text, token.i) for token in doc if token.like_num]` and then `print([text for text, _ in numbers])`.

Comment: So my requirement is I want to extract the the number and the text after the number in a list. example: 400 pounds, so I need the pounds in a list and 400 in a list.

Comment: @SharanIyer Your requirements now are quite different from those in the question. Do you mean [something like this](https://ideone.com/mOkBl1)?

Comment: Yess but I have to put them into seperate lists so I can add them into a DF later

Comment: I tried the same method for "१२ रुपये किलो" this type of sentence but it isnt matching the text after the number

Comment: @SharanIyer See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/7GoS7R).

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenize it and build your logic that way. Try this:

```
number_index = []
text = "४०० pounds of wheat at $ 3 per pound"
text_list = text.split(" ")

# Find which words are integers.
for index, word in enumerate(text_list):
    try:
        int(word)
        number_index.append(index)
    except:
        pass

# Now perform operations on those integers
for i in number_index:
    word = text_list[i]
    # do operations and put it back in the list

# Re-build string afterwards
```